# Chrome Extension not working with changed default_popup property

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

Following is my manifest.json content:

```
{
"update_url":"http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
"background": "background.html",
"browser_action":
                   {
                   "default_icon": "128.png",
                   "default_title": "Music",
                   "default_popup": "background.html"
                   },
"description": "abc" ,
"name": "Music Discovery" ,
"permissions": ["tabs"],
"version": "2.1",
"manifest_version": 2

}
```

Now although I had replaced the popup property with default_popup property but still its not working.
My background.html includes a simple UI which invokes a java script on the click of a button.
But its not working, Nothing is happening on clicking.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
{

    "name": "Music Discovery",
    "version": "2.1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "abc" ,

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false // add this line if you use event page.
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "128.png",
        "default_title": "Music",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }

}
```

I've never used "update_url" property, so I don't know where to place that.
But, I think your manifest.json should be like this.

I believe if you want to use popup that has UI, you are supposed to provide popup.html instead of background.html.

Background page only deal with logic, not view.

> My background.html includes a simple UI which invokes a java script on
>   the click of a button.

So, if you'd like to add a click event on a button in popup.html, write the code for adding click event in popup.js.

**popup.js**

```
document.getElementById('name-of-id').onclick = function() {
    //do something.
}
```

Then, import popup.js from popup.html like this.

**popup.html**

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```